# Referencing multiple tables from a single table and store additional data

Tags: database-design, sqlite

I have a database where I want to store lap time information from a racing game. I have tables for car, track, game, tuning and upgrade data and want to put all these together to create a single dataset, so that I can e.g. display all times for a track, or detailed information about a lap time on a specific track in a specific car.

My schema is:

```
Game
-------------
GameID (PK), GameName

Cars
-------------
CarID (PK), Manufacturer, Model, GameID (FK)

Tracks
-------------
TrackID (PK), TrackName

Parts
------------
PartID (PK), PartName, GameID (FK)

Tuning
-----------
TuneID (PK), ElementName, GameID (FK)

TrackGame (-- A Track can appear in multiple Games)
-----------
TrackID (FK), GameID (FK)
```

To achieve that, I created a table `TimeSet` where I want to put everything together, but since a car can have multiple `Parts` installed, and many different `Tuning` values, I'm having a hard time integrating this properly into a `TimeSet`. I though of splitting the data over three tables (see below), but I don't think this looks like a good solution, because inserting data cleanly will probably be difficult to do.

```
TimeSet
-----------
TimeSetID (PK), GameID (FK), TrackID (FK), CarID (FK), (TimeSetID, TuneID) (FK), (TimeSetID,PartID) (FK), time

Time_Tune
-----------
(TimeSetID (FK), TuneID (FK)) (PK), value

Time_Part
-----------
(TimeSetID (FK), PartID (FK)) (PK)
```

What is the proper way to do this? I'm working with SQLite 3 on Android.

Comment: Do parts and tunings apply to specific cars at specific times?  Do certain parts and tunings exist only in certain games, but cars exist across multiple games?  I don't fully understand the system you are trying to describe.  At first blush it seems like you might want a table that puts together a car with its tunings and parts on a specific date, record that date in TimeSet, and that should handle it.  I rather suspect I'm missing something, though.

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) No, I have cars, parts and tuning in my database per-game. There may be duplicates (e.g. two VW Golf in two different games), but they would have a different GameID, so they are still unique. Only tracks can appear in multiple games, since they are about 50% identically between games (The reason why `TrackGame` exists). The "date" (as in dd/mm/yy) isn't required, though it sounds like a good idea to add it. By "time" I mean in all cases "lap time" (as in "I needed 1:21:944 around the track").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're missing is a `car_configuration` table. This will have an FK to the `cars` table and have `car_config_parts` and `car_config_tunings` as children, like so:

```
create table car_configuration (
  config_id integer primary key,
  car_id integer references cars (car_id)
);

create table car_config_parts (
  config_id integer references car_configuration (config_id),
  part_id integer references parts (part_id),
  constraint car_config_part_pk primary key (config_id ,part_id)
);

create table car_config_tunings (
  config_id integer references car_configuration (config_id),
  tuning_id integer references tuning (tuning_id),
  constraint car_config_tuning_pk primary key (config_id, tuning_id)
);
```

You can then include the `config_id` as a reference in the `timeset` table (with no reference to `cars`). You'll need to ensure that you can't change the parts and tunings for a configuration or implement some form of versioning on this table to ensure you can reconstruct the exact details used to set a given time in the past.

Comment: Thanks, seems that my initial idea wasn't that far off. The configurations in a `timeset` row will be read-only after they are added, since it doesn't really make sense to alter them _after_ you did a lap with a specific setup. New laptime = new data record.